# How do I install gedit without Zeitgeist?

Tags: gedit, zeitgeist

I do not like this zeitgeist thingy. Because it is neither possible to (easily) configure it to shut up, nor is it possible to (easily) remove it without breaking other things.

Unfortunately, the useful editor "gedit" won't install without it. Apparently it has a built-in zeitgeist plugin.

So, my question is: is it possible to install gedit without this zeitgeist thing?

Update:

Manual configuration is not what I'm looking for - I have 30+ users (remotely connected) - should all users need to do this configuration tuning manually?

How does one start System Settings from a remote terminal at all?

Is it possible to disable this zeitgeist from one place for all users once and forever?

Comment: if you want to define your privacy settings - then this Q&A will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity

Comment: +1 because zeitgeist sucks, hogging like 100M of RAM at times

Answer (score 3):

First, uninstall the zeitgeist package and allow gedit to be automatically uninstalled. Then:

```
sudo su
apt-get download gedit
apt-get download gedit-plugins

dpkg --force-all -i gedit_3.6.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb gedit-plugins_3.6.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Just did this on Xubuntu 12.10 and it seems to be work fine on my system. Note that the exact name of the deb files will differ. You should disable the zeitgiest plugin which will still be installed in gedit, since presumably it won't work anyways.

(note: dpkg command borrowed from this question):

[How can I install a package without installing some dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent Zeitgeist from logging particular applications by adding them to a black list.

In Ubuntu 12.04, simply go to System Settings and click on Privacy (in the Personal section). Then hit the Applications tab and add gedit to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends gedit
```

It only installs the libzeitgeist library but not the full zeitgeist package.