# How do I not resolve unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I followed the answer to [How do I install gedit without Zeitgeist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142115/how-do-i-install-gedit-without-zeitgeist) and installed gedit without zeitgeist (in fact, zeitgeist is completely removed). gedit runs happily without zeitgeist.

Now I can't install anything else, because synaptic complains all the time that two packages (gedit and gedit-plugins) are broken; the update manager continually tries to upgrade zeitgeist from non-existent; installing another package "helpfully" tries to uninstall gedit & plugins, etc.

Is there a way to tell apt to STFU and not install zeitgeist and not uninstall gedit?
No, `apt-get -f install` is precisely what I do NOT want.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a dummy package with `equivs` that "provides" the dependency without actually providing anything. This *may* break things if they actually depended on something and you're faking it.

I've already answered this here: [How to trick apt dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29918/how-to-trick-apt-dependencies) but you would need to edit the control so that you had a "provides: zeitgeist" line in there somewhere (check the syntax on that too!)