# Why does asciidoc have texlive as a dependency?

Tags: apt, asciidoc

This is what happens when I try to install `asciidoc`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install asciidoc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dblatex docbook-utils jadetex latex-beamer latex-xcolor libgraphite3
  libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 lmodern luatex pgf prosper ps2eps tex-gyre texlive
  texlive-base texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-binaries texlive-common
  texlive-doc-base texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra
  texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc
  tipa xmlto
```

As far as I understand, it is completely unnecessary for the html and docbook backends: I would only need it if I want to generate latex files.

This question is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies), in the sense that it is not easy to install vanilla Tex Live on a Ubuntu / Debian (this is necessary for getting up-to-date versions of Tex Live components, sometimes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install asciidoc
```

Package can recommend another packages, if the maintainer think many people that use it will need the second one, or it has some features that needs it.

Comment: Great! I did not realize that apt-get installs recommended packages by default. In this case, it is the _optional_ `dblatex` that has texlive as a depend. Thank you!

Comment: And this is great right until you later run `apt-get dist-ugprade` and it installs all the recommended packages anyway because there is a new `asciidoc` version :-(