# How to update the software database?

Tags: apt, synaptic, latex, emacs

I have setup two disks on my computer, Ubuntu, `/` and `/home`. Later I found the disk space on `/` is not big enough (just 20G), so I installed my texlive to my own disk, somewhere under `$HOME`. Now I want to install emacs' auctex using `synaptic package manager`, but it says the prerequisite is to install the texlive.

I want to know is there a way to tell the `synaptic package manager`, that texlive has been installed?

Comment: How did you install texlive exactly?

Comment: I installed it to $HOME/local/texlive, and then set my path in `.bashrc` file

Comment: I asked how, not where.

Comment: Provided all your texlive environment variables are set correctly (which I'm guessing they are), [that way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies) will most likely work fine for this.