# Although I have Texlive installed from DVD apt-get suggests to install it every time, how can I avoid this behaviour?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, latex

I installed `TexLive 2014` on Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit LTS and now I would like to install other packages together with a `frontend` for Latex, namely **TexStudio**. The problem is that when I try to install only TexStudio the output is as follows and I hesitate to continue since it might mess up with my TexLive installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texstudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-lmodern latex-beamer latex-xcolor libptexenc1 lmodern luatex pgf
  prosper ps2eps tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-pstricks
  texlive-pstricks-doc
Suggested packages:
  chktex fragmaster xindy latexdiff lacheck latexmk dvidvi purifyeps dvipng
  psutils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-extra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lmodern latex-beamer latex-xcolor libptexenc1 lmodern luatex pgf
  prosper ps2eps tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-pstricks
  texlive-pstricks-doc texstudio
0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 264 MB of archives.
After this operation, 430 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

What can I do about it, this problem is even persistent with other commands such as building the dependencies required for a VIM installation as complete as possible. The output of that is below:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'vim' as source package instead of 'vim-gnome'
Note, selecting 'libgpm-dev' instead of 'libgpmg1-dev'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docbook-dsssl docbook-utils jadetex libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libgpm-dev
  liblua5.2-dev libosp5 libostyle1c2 libperl-dev libptexenc1 libreadline-dev
  libreadline6-dev libsgmls-perl libsp1c2 libxaw7-dev libxmu-dev
  libxmu-headers lua5.2 luatex lynx lynx-cur openjade sgmlspl sp tcl-dev
  tcl8.6-dev tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-recommended tipa
0 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 51,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 166 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Is there anything I can do to make `apt-get` recognize that newer versions of the pacakages are already installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who might me interested I am posting the solution here, giving credit tot the website of [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) which I learned the solution from.

Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian

To install vanilla TeX Live so that it replaces the Debian packages, perform the following steps:

```
Install vanilla TeX Live as root, system-wide.
Ensure that the only Debian TeX Live packages installed are tex-common, texinfo, and perhaps lmodern
Add TeX Live's bin directory to ENV_PATH in /etc/login.defs.
Tell APT about your TeX Live installation by building a dummy package using equivs:
$ aptitude install equivs # as root
mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs
equivs-control texlive-local
# edit texlive-local (see below)
$ equivs-build texlive-local
$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb
```

The site suggests editing the `texlive-local` file as follows for the latest installation of **TexLive 2014**.

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.4

Package: texlive-local
Version: 2014-1
Maintainer: you <you@yourdomain.example.org>
Provides: chktex, biblatex, biblatex-dw, cm-super, cm-super-minimal, context, 
 dvidvi, dvipng, feynmf, fragmaster, jadetex, lacheck, latex-beamer, 
 latex-cjk-all, latex-cjk-chinese, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp, 
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp, 
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp, latex-cjk-common, latex-cjk-japanese, 
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab, latex-cjk-korean, latex-cjk-thai, latexdiff, 
 latexmk, latex-sanskrit, latex-xcolor, lcdf-typetools, lmodern, luatex, 
 musixtex, passivetex, pgf, preview-latex-style, prosper, ps2eps, psutils, 
 purifyeps, t1utils, tex4ht, tex4ht-common, tex-gyre, texlive, texlive-base, 
 texlive-bibtex-extra, texlive-binaries, texlive-common, texlive-extra-utils,
 texlive-fonts-extra, texlive-fonts-extra-doc, texlive-fonts-recommended,
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc, texlive-font-utils, texlive-formats-extra,
 texlive-games, texlive-generic-extra, texlive-generic-recommended,
 texlive-humanities, texlive-humanities-doc, texlive-lang-african,
 texlive-lang-all, texlive-lang-arabic, texlive-lang-cjk, texlive-lang-cyrillic,
 texlive-lang-czechslovak, texlive-lang-english, texlive-lang-european,
 texlive-lang-japanese, texlive-lang-chinese, texlive-lang-korean,
 texlive-lang-french, texlive-lang-german, texlive-lang-greek, 
 texlive-lang-indic, texlive-lang-italian, texlive-lang-other, 
 texlive-lang-polish, texlive-lang-portuguese, texlive-lang-spanish,
 texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra, 
 texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-latex-recommended, 
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc, texlive-luatex, texlive-math-extra, 
 texlive-metapost, texlive-metapost-doc, texlive-music,
 texlive-omega, texlive-pictures, texlive-pictures-doc, texlive-plain-extra,
 texlive-pstricks, texlive-pstricks-doc, texlive-publishers,
 texlive-publishers-doc, texlive-science, texlive-science-doc, texlive-xetex,
 thailatex, tipa, tipa-doc, xindy, xindy-rules, xmltex 
Architecture: all
Description: My local installation of TeX Live 2014.
 A full "vanilla" TeX Live 2014
 http://tug.org/texlive/debian#vanilla
```

After installing this package I was able to install only TeXStudio without all the required `texlive` packages that it depends on.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, once you go out of the package system, you see things like that. You need to manage the dependencies by hand.
I see two options here. One, the cleaner but the more difficult, is to install the other packages by source.
The second option is to try to download the `.deb` package and installing it using the low level `dpkg -i` command, maybe forcing the installation without dependencies.
A very similar question is here:   [How can I install a package without installing some dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies)

Comment: I see so can I not trick the OS into thinking they are already installed somehow? I inspected some of the posts in the thread you pointed out and it occurred to me that it can be possible.

Comment: Never tried, but maybe http://askubuntu.com/a/18193/16395 ?

Comment: Okay I managed to do it with `equivs` package thanks for your help.