# How to install Nvidia drivers to use CUDA without also installing X11?

Tags: server, nvidia, software-installation, xorg, cuda

I have a headless box that will be used for CUDA computing. I installed Ubuntu server 16.04.1 but when I try to install the nVidia drivers via apt-get it also wants me to install X11 and other GUI components.

How can I just install the driver and CUDA libs without installing X11 and friends?

Ideally without downloading the run file directly from nVidia. I'd like to use debian packages if possible.

Comment: Look at the package dependencies. X11 should be there. A generic solution could be: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies The sad truth is that compute is still far from mainstream and often overlooked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to do this on recent versions of Ubuntu:

`sudo apt install --no-install-recommends nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-headless-440 nvidia-utils-440`

This won't install any X11 packages at all. Replace `440` with the driver version you want. `nvidia-utils` gives you `nvidia-smi` which is a CLI tool to show GPU utilization and temperature and other such information.

If `nvidia-smi` returns an error, check `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf` and comment out the line `alias nvidia off`. Then you can enable the driver with `sudo modprobe nvidia`.

Comment: More up-to-date: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-headless-510`.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit lightdm-
```

`lightdm` is the windows manager that `nvidia-*` installs. The dash at the end tells `apt-get` to uninstall the package but dependency resolution figures out not to install it in the first place. This still installed `xserver-common` (so you still get some X11 stuff) but it did not enable graphical booting. (Adding `xserver-common-` resulted in broken dependencies.)

PS. You're probably past this problem but this answer is for future internet generations.

Comment: Thank you. I can vouch that `ligthdm-` works, even when installing from the official deb.

Comment: Does this work with the official CUDA repo https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads on Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Comment: Following up with that logic, then installing CUDA on a headless system on Ubuntu 18.04LTS could be accomplished via: `apt-get install cuda gdm3-`. This would be via the cuda repo for Ubuntu. Test and report back.

Comment: Skipping the `nvidia-settings` graphical nVidia tool cuts things down a lot for me (on 19.10).  I'd like to also skip the xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-* package, but that's a hard requirement for the driver, which pulls in the X server junk.  So, `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435 nvidia-settings-` is about the best bet, IMO.  Add `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` onto that package list to get the useful cuda parts.

Comment: I've never seen the - suffix before. +1 for teaching me something I didn't know I was missing!

Answer (score 6):

`sudo apt-get -s install --no-install-recommends nvidia-current` seem to be rather sparse with the dependencies on my box, but it already has a full graphical environment.

What you could in theory do is:

1. Let apt-get download the pkg without install: `sudo apt-get -d install nvidia-current`
2. Pick up the desired deb from the cache: `ls /var/cache/apt/archives/ | grep nvidia-`
3. Install using dpkg, ignoring relevant dependencies: `dpkg -i --ignore-depends=package1,package2 package3.deb`

Dependencies are of course there for a reason, if I where in your situation I'd just let `apt` do its thing. Some X11-software won't hurt you much unless you run it.

Answer (score 1):

If running (say, Blender on a headless server, you don't need all those dependencies.

Download the CUDA drivers from as a runfile from:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Run `sudo sh cuda_8.0.44_linux.run` (or newer version)

Download the NVIDIA drivers from
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Run: `sudo sh /backup/iso/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run` (or newer version)

Note: Every time you update to a newer kernel, you'll have to reload the driver for that kernel. So you may want to add the "-a" (accept license terms) flag after going through them once.

My setup:

- headless Xubuntu 16.04
- dual GeForce 970 cards
- Blender 2.78

Enjoy!

Comment: Many unneeded dependencies not installed this way:`» apt-get -s install nvidia-current | grep newly`
0 upgraded, 65 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.