# NVIDIA Linux driver from the package manager has too many dependencies

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management

I run Ubuntu 16.04.5 x64 Server with XFCE Desktop and nouveau. Because of some proprietary applications having trouble with 3D rendering, I intend to install the NVIDIA driver.

The hardware is a Quadro from the Fermi series:

```
lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106GL [Quadro 2000] [10de:0dd8] (rev a1)
```

Now, the `nvidia-384`from the Ubuntu repo (aside, also the `nvidia-390` from the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`) has an insane amount of dependencies when I attempt to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install -s nvidia-384
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apg aptdaemon avahi-utils bbswitch-dkms bluez bluez-obexd cheese-common
  cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dconf-cli diffstat dkms
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts gcr geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-keyring gnome-menus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-guide
  gnome-user-share gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x gvfs-backends hardening-includes
  hwdata ibus im-config indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound ippusbxd iputils-arping
  libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1
  libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libassuan0 libavc1394-0 libcamel-1.2-54
  libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcgi-fast-perl
  libcgi-pm-perl libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclass-accessor-perl
  libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20
  libcrack2 libcuda1-384 libdata-alias-perl libdigest-hmac-perl
  libdouble-conversion1v5 libdv4 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-16
  libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25
  libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-21 libemail-valid-perl
  libexporter-tiny-perl libfcgi-perl libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0
  libfcitx-utils0 libfile-basedir-perl libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common
  libgdata22 libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames0
  libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnome-menu-3-0
  libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtop-2.0-10 libgtop2-common
  libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5
  libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7 libio-pty-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl
  libipc-system-simple-perl libjansson4 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblist-moreutils-perl libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy
  libmm-glib0 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libndp0 libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 liboauth0
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpanel-applet0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libperlio-gzip-perl
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqt5opengl5
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libraw1394-11 libshout3
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1
  libsignon-qt5-1 libsmbclient libsocket6-perl libsub-name-perl libtag1v5
  libtag1v5-vanilla libtext-levenshtein-perl libtimezonemap-data
  libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1
  liburl-dispatcher1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvdpau1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libwebpdemux1 libxnvctrl0 libyaml-libyaml-perl
  libyelp0 lightdm lintian mesa-vdpau-drivers mobile-broadband-provider-info
  modemmanager mountall mousetweaks nautilus-data network-manager
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp nvidia-opencl-icd-384
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1 p11-kit p11-kit-modules
  patchutils pinentry-gnome3 pkg-config policykit-1-gnome ppp pptp-linux
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-bs4 python3-cairo
  python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-html5lib python3-lxml
  python3-xdg screen-resolution-extra session-migration
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password
  signon-ui signon-ui-service signon-ui-x11 signond
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev t1utils ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces unity-control-center-signon
  unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon upstart usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data vdpau-driver-all wpasupplicant xserver-xorg-legacy yelp
  yelp-xsl
Suggested packages:
  bumblebee evolution evolution-data-server-dbg apache2-bin
  libapache2-mod-dnssd ibus-clutter ibus-doc ibus-qt4 click powerd
  unity-system-compositor zenity unity-greeter-session-broadcast libgles2-mesa
  | libgles2 libdv-bin oss-compat fcitx libhtml-template-perl
  libxml-simple-perl libraw1394-doc url-dispatcher bindfs binutils-multiarch
  libtext-template-perl nautilus avahi-autoipd
  network-manager-openconnect-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  network-manager-vpnc-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome pinentry-doc
  python3-genshi python3-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc python3-smbc
  libcanberra-gtk-module lightdm-remote-session-freerdp
  lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure remote-login-service graphviz
  upstart-monitor comgt wvdial libvdpau-va-gl1 nvidia-vdpau-driver
  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver wpagui libengine-pkcs11-openssl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apg aptdaemon avahi-utils bbswitch-dkms bluez bluez-obexd cheese-common
  cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dconf-cli diffstat dkms
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts gcr geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-keyring gnome-menus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-guide
  gnome-user-share gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x gvfs-backends hardening-includes
  hwdata ibus im-config indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound ippusbxd iputils-arping
  libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1
  libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libassuan0 libavc1394-0 libcamel-1.2-54
  libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcgi-fast-perl
  libcgi-pm-perl libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclass-accessor-perl
  libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20
  libcrack2 libcuda1-384 libdata-alias-perl libdigest-hmac-perl
  libdouble-conversion1v5 libdv4 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-16
  libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25
  libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-21 libemail-valid-perl
  libexporter-tiny-perl libfcgi-perl libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0
  libfcitx-utils0 libfile-basedir-perl libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common
  libgdata22 libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames0
  libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnome-menu-3-0
  libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtop-2.0-10 libgtop2-common
  libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5
  libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7 libio-pty-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl
  libipc-system-simple-perl libjansson4 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblist-moreutils-perl libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy
  libmm-glib0 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libndp0 libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 liboauth0
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpanel-applet0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libperlio-gzip-perl
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqt5opengl5
  libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5webkit5 libraw1394-11 libshout3
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1
  libsignon-qt5-1 libsmbclient libsocket6-perl libsub-name-perl libtag1v5
  libtag1v5-vanilla libtext-levenshtein-perl libtimezonemap-data
  libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1
  liburl-dispatcher1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvdpau1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libwebpdemux1 libxnvctrl0 libyaml-libyaml-perl
  libyelp0 lightdm lintian mesa-vdpau-drivers mobile-broadband-provider-info
  modemmanager mountall mousetweaks nautilus-data network-manager
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp nvidia-384 nvidia-opencl-icd-384
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1 p11-kit p11-kit-modules
  patchutils pinentry-gnome3 pkg-config policykit-1-gnome ppp pptp-linux
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-bs4 python3-cairo
  python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-html5lib python3-lxml
  python3-xdg screen-resolution-extra session-migration
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password
  signon-ui signon-ui-service signon-ui-x11 signond
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev t1utils ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces unity-control-center-signon
  unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon upstart usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data vdpau-driver-all wpasupplicant xserver-xorg-legacy yelp
  yelp-xsl
```

This clearly is a configuration issue. How can I install the driver with minimal dependencies and without the whole GNOME desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to winstall Nvidia drivers to use CUDA without also installing X11?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830983/how-to-winstall-nvidia-drivers-to-use-cuda-without-also-installing-x11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint @mikewhatever gave, the dependencies can indeed be drastically reduced by going with the answer of user697101 on the referred question, namely

```
apt-get install nvidia-390 lightdm-
```

after adding the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` repository. This gave me a working installation of the NVIDIA driver with few dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390 lightdm-
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'lightdm' is not installed, so not removed
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms libcuda1-390 libjansson4 libvdpau1 libxnvctrl0 mesa-vdpau-drivers
  nvidia-opencl-icd-390 nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1 pkg-config
  policykit-1-gnome screen-resolution-extra vdpau-driver-all
  xserver-xorg-legacy
Suggested packages:
  libvdpau-va-gl1 nvidia-vdpau-driver nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver
Recommended packages:
  nvidia-prime | bumblebee
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms libcuda1-390 libjansson4 libvdpau1 libxnvctrl0 mesa-vdpau-drivers
  nvidia-390 nvidia-opencl-icd-390 nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1
  pkg-config policykit-1-gnome screen-resolution-extra vdpau-driver-all
  xserver-xorg-legacy
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```